# How to grab information from a site using Microsoft Access, or other program?

Tags: ms-access

I have a database in Access with my movie collection and a very "professional" look. I would like to have a way to inform the IMDB's number of a movie and grab the information from the internet. Is there a way to read a page or download a page to read in automatically with MS-Access? If not, what language I should learn to have a database with this property?

Comment: Is "Access" being used just to store the tables, or you wanting to do your programming of your interface with IMDB within Access?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a loot at [this project](http://code.google.com/p/imdb-api/) implementing a IMDB API. It's .NET based so you should be able to integrate it with Access or any other C# or VB.NET application accessing your MSACCESS database.

Comment: wow - so fast - it seems it is what I need - I will study it.

Comment: "It's .NET...so you should be able to integrate it with Access" -- er, what? Access can't use .NET code. Of course, I'm assuming the original poster wants to implement something in Access, given that that's the only development environment mentioned in the question.